# (KeyError): MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple ... Why is this caused by a list, but not by a tuple?

Tags: pandas

This question is partially here to help me understand what lex-sorting is in the context of multi-indexes.

Say I have some MultiIndexed DataFrame df, and for the index I want to use:

```
a = (1, 1, 1)
```

So to pull the value from the dataframe I write:

```
df.loc[a, df.columns[i]]
```

Which works. But the following doesn't:

```
df.loc[list(a), df.columns[i]]
```

Giving me the error:

```
*** KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (1), lexsort depth (0)'
```

Why is this?

Also, another question, what does the following performance warning mean?

```
PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll illustrate the difference between passing a tuple and a list to `.loc`, using the example with `df` being

```
              0  1  2
first second         
bar   one     4  4  7
      two     3  4  7
foo   one     8  1  8
      two     7  5  4
```

Here `df.loc[('foo', 'two')]` returns the row indexed by this tuple, namely (7, 5, 4). The parameter specifies both levels of the multiindex.

But `df.loc[['foo', 'two']]` means you want all rows with the top level of the multiindex being **either** 'foo' or 'two'. A list means these are the options you want, and since only one level is provided in each option, the selection is based on the first (leftmost) level. The result:

```
              0  1  2
first second         
foo   one     8  1  8
      two     7  5  4
```

(Since there are no multiindices that begin with 'two', only those with 'foo' are present.)

Without seeing your dataframe, I can't tell where this difference leads to getting KeyError, but I hope the difference itself is clear now.